# java regular expression comma separated numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get 1 long (timestamp) and 3 floats out of the payload of a message, the string I am passing looks like this (ignore quotes):

```
"5737540811294,359.306580,7.948747,6.6707006621"
```

with this method

```
private static void processAnglesMsg(String s) {
   final Pattern dataTFFFsplit = Pattern.compile( "[+-]([0-9]+),"
                                                + "[+-]([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+,"
                                                + "[+-]([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+,"
                                                + "[+-]([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+,");
    Matcher data = dataTFFFsplit.matcher(s.trim());
    if(data.matches()) {
        Long time = Long.parseLong(data.group(1));
        float yaw = Float.parseFloat(data.group(2));
        float pitch = Float.parseFloat(data.group(3));
        float roll = Float.parseFloat(data.group(4));
        System.out.format("Angles - [%8d] Yaw: %08.3f Pitch: %08.3f Roll: %08.3f%n",time,yaw, pitch,roll);
    } else {
        if(debugLevel>=4) System.out.println("DEBUG processAnglesMsg: "+s);
    }
}
```

I keep reaching the debug code with:

> DEBUG processAnglesMsg: 5737540811294,359.306580,7.948747,6.6707006621*

so it looks like the pattern I have is not working and data.matches() is returning false, despite much searching I can't see what I have done wrong. I do want the pattern to allow for optional + or - even though my current data doesn't contain this.

Comment: Curious why not just use s.trim.split(",") and then do the `parse*`?

Comment: Did you know you can use `\d` instead of `0-9` -- although you might never be affected, it's more reliable under weird locales.

Comment: @slim the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) state that `\d` is a predefined character class for exactly `[0-9]`. Localization shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: @slim in java `\d === [0-9]`

Comment: Thanks both. This is true in Java, but it's probably worth picking up the habit for other languages and for other pedefined character classes (in some locales in UNIX, `[a-d]` might be `[aAbBcCdD]`!)

Comment: So should I have (for example) "([+-]?[0-9]+)," in my pattern?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your sub-`Pattern`s is that the `+` / `-` sign is not optional and will not match in your example (also the last sub-pattern requires a comma, but your example doesn't end with one).

Assuming your example `String`s will never contain a comma for localized number separating purposes, and that you do not want to use a CSV parsing framework:

```
String example = "5737540811294,359.306580,7.948747,6.6707006621";
// splits the input based on comma
String[] split = example.split(",");
// parses desired data types
// will throw runtime NumberFormatException if something's un-parseable
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(split[0]));
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat(split[1]));
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat(split[2]));
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat(split[3]));
```

**Output** (values rounded)

```
5737540811294
359.30658
7.948747
6.6707006
```

**Note**

You can also use `BigDecimal` instead of `Float` if you wish to keep as many decimals as possible.

For instance:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(split[3]));
```

**Output**

```
6.6707006621
```

Comment: yep. much better to split on ','.

Comment: Thanks that works a treat, I shouldn't have tried to over complicate it, I will use that solution. If anybody can tell me what I did do wrong in my method I would like to learn the correct regex.

Comment: @gjwo you're welcome. If you refresh the page, you'll see what's wrong with your original pattern at the start of my answer.

Comment: In general, if a regex starts looking complicated, you should ask yourself whether a regex was the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use a scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(",");
long time = scanner.nextLong();
float yaw = scanner.nextFloat();
float pitch = scanner.nextFloat();
float roll = scanner.nextFloat();
```

Easier to code and easier to read.

---

If the input will not always match:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(",");
try {
    long time = scanner.nextLong();
    float yaw = scanner.nextFloat();
    float pitch = scanner.nextFloat();
    float roll = scanner.nextFloat();
    System.out.format("Angles - [%8d] Yaw: %08.3f Pitch: %08.3f Roll: %08.3f%n",time,yaw, pitch,roll);
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    // input didn't match due to insufficient elements or parsing failure
}
```

Comment: Good one too, and no boxing overhead. Well, no "boxing" but some *flying* apparently :)